# How to Fetch Comments from a Public Facebook Video using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm Unable to Fetch Comments from a Public Facebook Video using Graph API, but Can Access Basic Video Details

I'm working on a project where I aim to fetch comments from a public Facebook video using the Graph API. I've set up an app on the Facebook Developer Dashboard and obtained both an app access token and a user access token. When I try to fetch basic details about the video, it works perfectly. However, when I attempt to fetch the comments, I receive a `(#200) Missing Permissions` error.

**Working Endpoint**:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{video-id}?access_token={my-user-access-token}
```

**Result**:

```
{'description': 'Most Jaw-Dropping Assassination! ', 'updated_time': '2023-10-05T13:06:55+0000', 'id': '2707002789439813'}
```

**Non-working Endpoint**:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{video-id}/comments?access_token={my-user-access-token}
```

**Error**:

```
{'error': {'message': '(#200) Missing Permissions', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 200, 'fbtrace_id': 'AL-27I8dXedNm4VnbMLwmRI'}}
```

I've requested the following permissions for my app:
`user_location  user_likes  user_events  email  read_insights  publish_video  pages_show_list  business_management  instagram_manage_comments  pages_read_engagement  pages_read_user_content  public_profile`

This is my first time setting up a Facebook app, and I'm unsure if I'm missing some specific permissions that are not listed above. If so, how can I obtain them? Additionally, could this issue be related to my app needing a review by Facebook?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

[1] This is the full list of permissions that is available to my app, none of them seem pertinent:

```
Commerce Permissions
instagram_shopping_tag_products
User Data Permissions
email
gaming_user_locale
user_age_range
user_birthday
user_friends
user_gender
user_hometown
user_likes
user_link
user_location
user_messenger_contact
user_photos
user_posts
user_videos
Events Groups Pages
ads_management
ads_read
attribution_read
business_management
groups_access_member_info
groups_show_list
page_events
pages_manage_ads
pages_manage_cta
pages_manage_engagement
pages_manage_instant_articles
pages_manage_metadata
pages_manage_posts
pages_messaging
pages_messaging_phone_number
pages_messaging_subscriptions
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content
pages_show_list
publish_to_groups
read_page_mailboxes
user_events
user_managed_groups
Other
catalog_management
instagram_basic
instagram_content_publish
instagram_manage_comments
instagram_manage_insights
instagram_manage_messages
leads_retrieval
manage_fundraisers
private_computation_access
publish_video
read_insights
user_payment_tokens
whatsapp_business_management
whatsapp_business_messaging
```